# What is method return type of class InfoChyb

Tags: java, object, return-type

Could you pls help me to understand why we can address to variable message this way -e.message? Does it work so that chyb.getInfoMessage(2) return new object of type Chyb and this result we need to assign to varialbe of the same type Chyb. And when e is of type Chyb, we can address all variables in class Chyb that were thanks to constructor filled with data?

Program is here:

```
class Chyb{
  String message;
  int importance;

  Chyb(String m, int i){
    message= m;
    importance = i;
  }
}

class InfoChyb {
  String message[] = {
    "Input error",
    "output error",
    "disk is full",
    "Index is out of range"
 };
 int howBad[] = { 3, 3, 2, 4 };

 Chyb getInfoMessage(int i) {
   if(i >=0 & i < message.length)
     return new Chyb(message[i], howBad[i]);
   else
     return new Chyb("Not valid code" , 0);
  }
 }


class InfoChyb {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    InfoChyby chyb = new InfoChyby();
    Chyb e;

    e = chyb.getInfoMessage(2);
    System.out.println("Importance of message " + e.message+ ":" + 
    e.importance);
    e = chyb.getInfoMessage(19);
    System.out.println("Importance of message " + e.message+ ":" + 
    e.importance);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hum ... what is the question ? You might want to see [ask]

Comment: I just only needed to know if my explanation of understanding this program and specially method return type is correct :-)

Comment: next time provide a sample in english, this one not as easy to understand

Comment: OK next time I will translate it.

Comment: It would be better if you learned to write code in English right from the start. It's the common programmer language after all.

Comment: Ok I agree. Next time all in English, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer this, but there is a lot of affirmations in each point, so bear with me here.

> 1. class Chyb is just normal class with two variables String and int and with one constructor.

Correct

> 2. class InfoChyby has two variables(fields) also of type String and int

Those variables are arrays, `String[]` and `int[]`.

> 3. method zjistiInfoChyby is of type Chyb, which is class and it is so because it needs to return two values of different types String and int. [...]

method `zjistiInfoChyby` have a return type of `Chyb`

> 3. [...] Then this method returns new object of type Chyb, which means that it calls constructor of class Chyb and pass there values in brackets, right?

You instantiate a `Chyb` to hold the values. If the index provided in argument is correct, you will get this from the arrays `zpravy[]`, `jakzle[]` or you return an instance with "default value" `return new Chyb("Neplatny kod chyby" , 0);`

> 4. class InfoChyb is with method main and runns the program. [...]

Yes,the `main` method could be in any class.

> 4. [...] we define variable e of type Chyb and this is because this value will have inside link from returned method zjistiInfoChyby that contains two variales of type String and int

A `Chyb` is declare to hold the result of the method call.

Comment: Note that this might not be complete @Domorodec, if you want to get confirmation on some specific point, you should check [ask], this format of question is not the best, especially if you don't focus on a problem. The verbosity and the fact that the code is not in english add some complexity, I don't have a context here so I can't add explanations on why.

Comment: Yes I know some people wrote me about writting in english. Next time will do so :-)